# Keyboard based teleop pkg for generic stage simulated robots

Tags: simulation, teleop, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Greetings,

Is any package available for tele-operating  robots in robot in stage/gazebo using keyboard. I am trying hands on move_base_gmapping_5cm.launch in navigation_stage package.

keyboard_teleop.launch from turtlebot_teleop package is not able to make robot move.
Is it possible for anyone to share package written for such task?

prince

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29399/keyboard-based-teleop-pkg-for-generic-stage-simulated-robots/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I often use the [pr_teleop](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_teleop) package for simple teleop tasks as it publishes on the 'cmd_vel' topic by default and can easily be started using

```
rosrun pr2_teleop teleop_pr2_keyboard
```

You can find much more comprehensive answers [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/9207/teleop_base-deprecated-need-generic-teleop-package).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-03-16**:
i found erratic_teleop package also useful